# Utilizar CASE dentro de un WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Tengo la siguiente consulta **SQL Server**:

```sql
SELECT
  ro.REPORT_NUMBER,
  ro.OBJECT_ID,
  ro.OBJECT_NAME,
  r.OBJECT_CLASS,
  s.SAMPLE_NUMBER,
  s.PROJECT
FROM REPORTS r,
  REPORT_OBJECTS ro,
  SAMPLE s
WHERE
  (ro.REPORT_NUMBER = r.REPORT_NUMBER)
  AND CASE
    WHEN r.OBJECT_CLASS = 'PROJECT' THEN s.PROJECT = ro.OBJECT_NAME
  END
```

La idea es que cuando `r.object_class` sea igual a `PROJECT` se compare `s.PROJECT` con `ro.OBJECT_NAME`. De la misma manera, si `object_class` es igual a `SAMPLE` se compare `s.SAMPLE_NUMBER` con `ro.OBJECT_ID`.

La duda es, ¿se podrá realizar la consulta de esta manera o debo cambiar la estructura para hacerlo de otra forma?

Se produce un error en el `'='`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que la consulta que realizas no requiere del `CASE`. Lo solucionas de forma más simple. Enlazas siempre la tabla `SAMPLE`, mostrando resultados siempre que exista `r.OBJECT_CLASS = 'PROJECT'`

```
select ro.REPORT_NUMBER,ro.OBJECT_ID, ro.OBJECT_NAME, r.OBJECT_CLASS, s.SAMPLE_NUMBER, s.PROJECT 
FROM REPORTS r
INNER JOIN REPORT_OBJECTS ro on ro.REPORT_NUMBER = r.REPORT_NUMBER
INNER JOIN SAMPLE s ON s.PROJECT = ro.OBJECT_NAME
WHERE r.OBJECT_CLASS = 'PROJECT'
```

**EDITO**
Si necesitas otros casos específicos, dudo que lo puedas meter en la misma consulta, deberás realizar un `UNION`. Por ejemplo

```
select ro.REPORT_NUMBER,ro.OBJECT_ID, ro.OBJECT_NAME, r.OBJECT_CLASS, s.SAMPLE_NUMBER, s.PROJECT 
FROM REPORTS r
INNER JOIN REPORT_OBJECTS ro on ro.REPORT_NUMBER = r.REPORT_NUMBER
INNER JOIN SAMPLE s ON s.PROJECT = ro.OBJECT_NAME
WHERE r.OBJECT_CLASS = 'PROJECT'
UNION ALL
select ro.REPORT_NUMBER,ro.OBJECT_ID, ro.OBJECT_NAME, r.OBJECT_CLASS, s.SAMPLE_NUMBER, s.PROJECT 
FROM REPORTS r
INNER JOIN REPORT_OBJECTS ro on ro.REPORT_NUMBER = r.REPORT_NUMBER
INNER JOIN SAMPLE s ON s.SAMPLE_NUMBER = ro.OBJECT_ID 
WHERE r.OBJECT_CLASS = 'SAMPLE'
```

Comment: esta bien, de esta manera puedo cubrir en caso de que object_class sea 'PROJECT', pero me queda la duda al momento de  object_class ='SAMPLE'.

Comment: tendria que tener ademas del ultimo inner join algo como esto. 
INNER JOIN SAMPLE s ON s.SAMPLE_NUMBER = ro.OBJECT_ID
WHERE r.OBJECT_CLASS = 'SAMPLE'

Comment: @Matias Navarro, he editado la respuesta por si te sirve.

Answer (score 1):

Para empezar, lo que tienes no debería de ser un `WHERE` sino parte de un 
`JOIN`. Así quedaría mejor explicado lo que quieres hacer.

```
select  ro.REPORT_NUMBER,
        ro.OBJECT_ID,
        ro.OBJECT_NAME,
        r.OBJECT_CLASS,
        s.SAMPLE_NUMBER,
        s.PROJECT 
FROM  REPORTS r
JOIN REPORT_OBJECTS ro ON ro.REPORT_NUMBER = r.REPORT_NUMBER
--LEFT?
JOIN SAMPLE s ON (r.OBJECT_CLASS = 'PROJECT' AND s.PROJECT = ro.OBJECT_NAME)
              OR (r.OBJECT_CLASS = 'SAMPLE' AND s.SAMPLE_NUMBER = ro.OBJECT_ID);
```

La sintaxis que usaste es una que está obsoleta y debe evitarse.

**EDIT:** Para tener múltiples opciones, solo necesitas trabajar un poco la lógica por medio de paréntesis y los operadores lógicos (AND,OR).

El CASE no puede regresar un valor booleano (verdadero o falso), solo un valor con un tipo válido de SQL Server.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, pero igualmente necesito hacer consultas a campos diferentes dependiendo del caso. Estoy tratando de efectuar mis consultas aplicando el join jeje

Comment: Edité la respuesta para que veas como se puede hacer. La opción de UNION ALL mencionada en la otra respuesta puede servir para aprovechar mejor los índices en caso de que existan los adecuados.

Comment: muchas gracias, he probado mediante las dos respuestas, esta parece ser un poco mas facil de comprender, pero con el union all y efectuando las dos consultas por separado la consulta se ejecuta mas rápido.